# Tableview in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, tableview

```
TableColumn<Product,String> col=new TableColumn<>("name");
col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
```

This code is used to create columns for tableview. I'm not able to understand how the code works. I do know that concepts like properties and callbacks are involved but I just have a basic idea about them,and I don't get how these concepts tie together to make the above code run. Could someone break it down for me in simple terms?

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. What you can do is take a look at the source code to figure out how it works.

Comment: Or just read the documentation: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellValueFactoryProperty), and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html)